# How to use Firefox Containers with Python (instead of Firefox Profiles)

Tags: firefox, python, firefox-profile, selenium

I have a python script for an automation tool using selenium that requires using multiple accounts (tens & hundreds) using Firefox. Thing is, I can't login-logout the accounts, so to use multiple and to keep them isolated from each other I used FireFox profiles. For each account I have created a Firefox profile where the account in logged on, and the code loops through the profiles to use the accounts. 
The problem with this method is that it takes up too much space, tens of GBs, which is not a problem on my PC but will be when I later on upload it to the cloud. 
I have seen that FireFox containers too isolate the accounts from eachother and don't have the need to logout/login, but I haven't found any guide on the internet on how to switch containers with Python Selenium. *Is it even possible? If yes, how?* 

**PS:** The tool is not for anything illegal, I have the rights to automate.